# gulp watch seems to freeze in Docker

Tags: javascript, docker, gulp, boot2docker, gulp-watch

I'm trying to "dockerize" our development environment. We have a gulp build system that watches changes to our js/sass/jade files. This is all setup to work just fine outside of docker.

I've created a docker container and I mount my code base into it (using a volume). All the precursor npm installs and bower installs finish successfully. My last step runs gulp and it runs properly and builds but then does not pick up any subsequent changes to any of our js/sass/jade files.

I'm running the build system with the following command:

`docker run -it -v $(pwd):/code/ client gulp reset`

Does anyone have a similar setup in their development environment? What did you do to get your gulp watch to work and display the building?

EDIT: I guess I could do the gulp build/watch outside of docker and only mount the generated files but I'd rather contain that all inside of docker so that the host machine doesn't need to worry about any dependencies to build/run our app

EDIT2: Here are my dockerfile and docker-compose.yml

```
#Dockerfile
FROM node:0.12.5
RUN mkdir /code

WORKDIR /code
RUN mkdir client
WORKDIR client
RUN mkdir .tmp
ADD ./client/package.json /code/client/package.json
ADD ./client/bower.json /code/client/bower.json

RUN npm install gulp -g
RUN npm install bower -g
RUN npm install
RUN npm rebuild node-sass
RUN bower --allow-root install

CMD gulp reset
```

and

```
client:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/code
```

Comment: Have a look at the 10 gulp in the hub https://registry.hub.docker.com/search?q=gulp&searchfield=

Comment: @user2915097 i dont think the problem is how im creating the image. ive editted the original post with my dockerfile and docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 3):

I've never been able to get any inotify-based file watcher to ever work over with virtual-box guest additions, and based on [this ticket](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10660?cversion=0&cnum_hist=1) it's unlikely to be available anytime soon. My preferred approach is the following:

- Assuming my local source code is in /code
- Run my watcher locally on /code
- When a change is detected, rsync local /code to remote /code (mounted as a container-only volume) in the container

Example rsync:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from sourcecode my/image \
    rsync \
        --delete \
        --recursive \
        --safe-links \
        --exclude .git  --exclude node_modules  \
    /local/repo/ /container/repo
```

This avoids lots of issues and allows you to get granular with what you want your container environment to see.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I actually got docker working with gulp watch so long as I use the option usePolling: true

The performance is actually very poor though. How do you rsync from local to the docker container?

Comment: Yeah you can poll but that is terrible on CPU as you noticed. I've edited the answer to show an example rsync.